# How to use textscan and then save that text file file as a mat file?

Tags: matlab, mat, textscan

I have unsigned feature vectors stored in a text file named `data1.txt`. How can I use `textscan` in a code below to extract these FV as dimensions are too much (50 rows and 262144 columns) and store them in a mat file?

```
clc;

clear all;

close all;

fileID = fopen('data1.txt','w');

 for i=1:50

a=num2str(i);

I = imread(strcat(a,'.png'));

I=entropyfilt(I);% filtering 50 images

I = double(I)/255;

fv = hog_feature_vector(I); % extracting feature vectors of 50 images

fileID = fopen('data1.txt','a');% saving those FV in a specific format in text             

   fprintf(fileID,'\t');

   fprintf(fileID,'%1.4f\t',fv);

  fprintf(fileID,'\n');

 end

fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: I moved your problem statement before your code snippet. It's usually easier to read code with some context. I also indented your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K (clicking `{}` would also have worked). I also added the [tag:matlab] tag for better visibility; this also lets Stack Overflow highlight your code properly. Unfortunately I'm still not able to understand your question. Please [edit] it and add as much clarification as you can.

Comment: edited my query